# Deleting Row of Datagrid by clicking a button part of that row in Delete column?

Tags: apache-flex, datagrid, row, itemrenderer

I want to delete a row of my datagrid when someone click a button part of that row located below Delete Column. I tried many different way one of those were to

```
<mx:DataGrid id="userGrid" dataProvider="{userGridData}" width="800" height="500" itemClick="userGrid_itemClickHandler(event)" creationComplete="userGrid_creationCompleteHandler(event)">
        <mx:columns>
            <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="ID" dataField="user_id" />

            <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="Email" dataField="user_email"/>

            <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="Delete" itemRenderer="ev.renderers.UserGridDelete" id="deleteCol"/>
            <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="Edit" itemRenderer="ev.renderers.UserGridEditRender"/>

        </mx:columns>
    </mx:DataGrid>
```

The item render ev.renderers.UserGridEditRender has a delete button listing for click event it basically do `userGridData.removeItemAt(userGrid.selectedIndex);`
(UserGridData = Data provider of grid with id "userGrid")
But whenever I click the button an exception is throw

```
RangeError: Index '-1' specified is out of bounds.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about having your item renderer button dispatch an event that has the selected "data" in it.

```
dispatchEvent( new DataMonkeyEvent(DataMonkeyEvent.DELETE_ROW, this.data) );  //where "this" is the button and the event should bubble.
```

listen for that event in the outer document and edit your userGridData accordingly... invalidateList() if you are not using in-house extended dataproviders that listen for children changed jive.

Hope that helps. --jeremy

Comment: I have already tried this , interestingly the exception is thrown for rows with index 0 and 1 only , for rest it works good.

Comment: You'll have to show code then.  In your example you should not be referencing "deleteCol".  The other issue is that (as your code is saying), you don't have a selected index.  Click somewhere else in the grid first (email column), then use your delete button.